# R find two words into same string

Tags: r, string

I want to create a single regex or str_detect (if possible) to search through text strings and determine if two words (countries) occur in the same string based on one country list, but testing without repetition. For example:

```
latam <- c("BRAZIL", "MEXICO", "CHILE", "ARGENTINA", "COLOMBIA", "CUBA", "VENEZUELA", "PERU", "COSTA RICA", "ECUADOR", "URUGUAY", "BOLIVIA", "PARAGUAY", "GUATEMALA", "EL SALVADOR", "PANAMA", "NICARAGUA", "DOMINICAN REPUBLIC", "HONDURAS", "HAITI")

example_string <- c("USA;BRAZIL", "USA;BRAZIL;ARGENTINA", "BRAZIL;BRAZIL;ARGENTINA", "BRAZIL;ARGENTINA", "BRAZIL;BRAZIL", "BRAZIL;BRAZIL;ARGENTINA;ARGENTINA")
```

Testing `example_string`, the desired output is: `FALSE`, `TRUE`, `TRUE`, `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a data.table solution (for sure there's a regex for this, but...)

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(example_string)
```

create a data.table with the test string

```
 a[, countries := sapply(example_string, strsplit, ";")]
```

split the countries, so each one can be tested individually

```
a[, sum(unique(countries[[1]]) %in% latam) >= 2, by = example_string]
```

find how many UNIQUE countries of each row are in the `latam` list and check if the number is equal or greater than 2.

Comment: Why put it into a data.table though? Why not just `sapply(strsplit(example_string, ";"), function(x) sum(unique(x) %in% latam) >= 2 )` ?

Comment: While not a regex solution, it still solves what I needed. I combined both approaches from PavoDive and @thelatemail Thanks!